# OpenHTMLToPDF Text has no space in generated PDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I am using OpenHTMLToPDF C# library to generate PDF from HTML.
Few words in my PDF generated doesn't have space in between letters. For example **And** **Certificate**.

[image] [image]

There is no space between letters **A & n**, **r & t**

Below is my sample code and the styles I have applied to my HTML.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kerning is a huge problem with wkhtmltopdf; I would not bother trying to fix it. Maybe try a different font or ask in the github repo?

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. We are trying selectpdf (community edition) which is giving better results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by using a different font for my html

use this property:

- font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;

in your body to change the whole font, hopefully this will help you out.